# VB .net changing code while debugging sets variables to nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

[image]

Normally, while stepping through VB code I can change code and continue.
Beginning this week, when I change code, for instance deleting a line with "stop" or changing any code, I may or may not get the above error popup, and the variables all become "Nothing" and I must restart the program.

LONG TERM VS MALFUNCTION...
This is a malfunction I've seen in VS for about 10 years now, on many different PC's, on the last 10 years of Windows.

The problem comes and goes.  I haven't seen it since last year.  Now, suddenly it's back.

I'm using Windows 10, and the latest VS.
Project is Windows app.

**UPDATE**
I did Tools menu > Import and Export Settings.. > Reset all settings
..and edit-and-go started working again.  But now a day later, it doesn't work again.

And I moved static variables from the method scope to the class scope.

I uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2019 Pro... NO EFFECT
I tried running as ADMIN...NO EFFECT
I deleted all OBJ and VS within project folder...NO EFFECT

Still get this SERIOUS VISUAL STUDIO MALFUNCTION.  And for 10 years!
Microsoft, please help me fix it.

Comment: If you can reproduce it reliably it may be worth recording your screen and filing it as a bug for the VS guys to review

Comment: Good idea.  I will do it.

Comment: Still no response from VS guys.  So sad.  I've encountered this bug at multiple jobs and many different laptops, and on all versions of VS and Windows over the last 10 years.

Comment: And what does the error list window say the reason is for needing to restart? There have always been contexts that cannot continue, such as "adding a try catch around the active statement will prevent edit and continue from working" or adding/removing an async call etc